# streaming audio from parse for ios swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, avplayer, audio-streaming

I have a code to stream audio from parse on ios build in swift after compiling everything seems OK and the audio files sync accurately but when i select them there is no audio coming out of the speakers. on swift 2 its not compiling anymore its saying ambiguous use of url, here is the func written in swift ,i hope we can convert it to swift 2 thank you:

```
    func grabSong(){
    let SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "songs")
    SongQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block:{

        (object: PFObject?, error:NSError?)-> Void in

        if let AudioFileURLTemp = object?.objectForKey("songFile")?.url {

           AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: AudioFileURLTemp! ))
        AudioPlayer.play()
        }
})
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it's working,
Only you need to check the optionality, like this:

```
    func grabSong() {
    let SonQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    SonQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(idArray[SelectedSongNumber], block: {
        (object: PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if let audioFIleTemp: PFFile = object?.valueForKey("SongFile") as? PFFile {
            AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: audioFIleTemp.url!)!)
            AudioPlayer.play()
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this (I don't have any audio files on parse currently), however, why not just access the pffile and then convert to a url? It would look something like this:

```
func grabSong(){
        let SongQuery = PFQuery(className: "songs")
        SongQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block:{

            (object: PFObject?, error:NSError?)-> Void in

            if let songFile: PFFile = object?.valueForKey("songFile") as? PFFile {
                AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: songFile.url)
                AudioPlayer.play()
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Hello I tried your code but its not building im getting an error. Cannot convert value of type 'string' to expected argument type 'NSURL' any clue?